# going about sharing information in ios between views

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I've just a general theory question i was hoping to generate some responses. I've been learning ios and have a project with one view i'm tinkering with.  It has a run loop that manages a socket that connects to a server and gets chat as it comes in.  a textview is updated with new chat.  Now this textview is attached to story board one. I'm going to ask now if they go to story board two when i add it (i'm reading up on this multi page aspect now), would the chat in view one continue to update though the user of course would not see it till they return o the view.  The second question is could i update story board 2 and one at the same time in the first view controller. I saw you can pass variables to story board 2 in my book in the segue, but can my socket run loop which lives in view controller one access view controller two variables.  If not it sounds like i need to investigate some kind of queue to communicate updates from telnet to story board 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're starting off with a pretty complicated project - very impressed.  Here are a couple of quick notes on storyboard and segues.

- if you setup your storyboard using a view controller then setup a segue to another view controller - when you segue the new view controller is created, the original is still in memory and can still respond to notifications or callbacks if you program it that way.

  - when you "pop" or "dismiss" your view controller you segued to, it is gone from memory.
  - when you segue, you automatically get a reference to the new view controller in a method that is called `prepareForSeque`.  You can store this reference in a property and use that property to update it as needed.

So here is a pseudo example:

- view controller a has some network code, i'm guessing when the buffer is filled it calls a method in view controller a.  Let's call it networkMethod as a reference.  in side of network method, let say you end up with a string and you want to pass that string over to your view controller b so you can do something with it there.  So instead of just setting a variable, we'll pass it in a method, so you can do something with it.  Hopefully that scenario is on target with your needs, otherwise the rest of my example will be off base.

task - setup a reference for view controller b.
  in the import section of your view controller a .h file

```
#import "ViewControllerB.h"  //this is the name of your view controller b class
```

in view controller a in the interface section (.h file) add:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) ViewControllerB *viewB;
```

in your .m file you would trigger you segue - maybe on a button or some action.  sounds like you already have this:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"viewB" sender:self];
```

Now create a new method that looks like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    self.viewB = segue.destinationViewController;  //this stores a reference for later
```

}

Now in your callback method you can reference view controller b like this:

```
-(void)networkCallbackMethod:(NSString*)stringData {

    if (self.viewB) {

     [self.viewB myCustomMethodUsingPassedData:stringData];

    }


}
```

then finally in view controller b you would have the matching method like this:

```
-(void)myCustomeMethodUsingPassedData:(NSString*)stringData {
     //update the view here
}
```

that should roughly provide you a framework where you can setup two view controllers, segue and grab a reference and then update the new view controller as needed.

hope that helps. good luck.

Comment: this looks basically like what i'm looking for.  Just a path to create sharing between the two views.  I gave this a close read and will look to see if i can set some of this up.  I semi assumed there have to be some information sharing ability that was robust enough to keep views all in similar states and looks like there is. In my reading i saw that there was variable passing possible between the views but did not have a lot of data on it so far. thanks

Comment: I highlighted a model that is pretty common for passing data from the - lets call it parent to the child or next view controller.  what is powerful using this approach is that you can pass data or even call methods in that child instance.  Now if you want the child to "talk back" the common pattern is "protocol & delegate".  There is much written about it here on stack overflow, so just search for it.  best of luck.

Comment: telnet done bugs fixed and i started working with these ideas.  First i had to figure out how to assign a view controller to the new storyboard page which i did and then i used your method to assign viewb in the seque, i went a little futher and named the segue and checked for that one, did nslog(viewb) assigned and its working thanks:)